# How can I change the background-color of a div inside a link

Tags: html, css, class, visited

Is it possible to change the background-color of a div inside a link using only a :visited pseudo class and without using Javascript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
            a:hover {background-color:blue;}
            a:visited {background-color:green;}

           .smallbox {
            background-color: #666;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
           }
           .smallbox:hover {background-color:blue;}
           .smallbox:visited {background-color:green;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#"><div class="smallbox"></div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `div` elements should not be inside `a` elements. It's not a valid html structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can do this. Just remember the visited pseudo class belongs to the link, not the div.

```css
a:hover .smallbox {background-color:blue;}
a:visited .smallbox {background-color:green;}
a:visited .smallbox:hover {background-color:blue;}

 .smallbox {
  display: block;
  background-color: #666;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<a href="##"><span class="smallbox"></span></a>
```

As pointed out by  Dekel in the comments, a div inside an anchor element is invalid HTML. You could cheat and put a span inside the link and set its display property to "block", but that's probably not really better.

If you just need a link that behaves like a block element rather than an inline element, consider switching the anchor tag's display property to `block` and removing the inner element entirely as suggested in this post: [<div> within <a>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816813/div-within-a)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying it to a div, why not apply it directly to the "a" tags, as you did, and remove the div? Why do you need it? `a: hover { background-color:blue; }` should work just fine. You just need to add a `display:block` to the `a:hover` style, as well.

Or, if you have multiple `a` tags on the page and only want to apply it to one of them, you can use an id and apply it to that:

```
<a id="someId" href="#">My Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
#someId {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
}
```